# Cast sum(column) as varchar

Tags: sql, casting, sql-server-2000, aggregate-functions

I am trying to do the following:

```
select @revenue = '$' + cast(sum(amount) as varchar)
    from revenue
    where reportId = @reportId
```

But I am getting the error:

> Syntax error converting the varchar value '$9.83314e+006' to a column
>   of data type int.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what datatype is the revenue column?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like your `@revenue` variable is declared as an int.  Is it?  If so, it needs to be varchar(x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `@revenue` must be defined as an `int` - yes?

Comment: Oh- yes- that's it! Thanks! I missed that and just couldn't figure out what was wrong...